# res.render() is not working?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm having a problem rendering a html page using express.

Here's my code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url, true);

request.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    if (request.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(data._id);
        res.render('user-home.html', { userId: data._id });    //this doesn't work
    }
}, false);

request.send(JSON.stringify(j));
```

The index.html is being rendered, but user-home.html is not.

Comment: can you share the log?

Comment: This is the terminal log: 

`$ PORT=8081 node server.js
hab2017 app listening on port 8081
5896ccb5ad0405265cdf4979
nooooooo`

Comment: `res.render` must have a template engine, do you set your static route ??
is everything ok with your configs??

Comment: I do have a template engine. It's set as `app.engine('html', engines.hogan)` and the route is set as `app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates')`

Comment: i think you should not use `.html` , just try `user-home` or rename and try `userHome`

Comment: Is this client side code or server side code? Where is `res` defined? What messages are being reported on the console (browser or node consoles).